# The border radius on the edges of the picture

Tags: html, css

I want to create here is such a curved line along the edges of images when hovering:
[image]

I have created everything except these lines, don't know how to do

Comment: Have you at least *attempted* **anything?**

Comment: @AndrewL. of course, added a mask with a dark background on an image and position absolute...

Comment: Please include that in the question and why it didn't work

Comment: @AndrewL. can somewhere to throw my bootstrap code? something like jsfiddle... I would have posted my code

Comment: JSFiddle would be great. Just include the external resource

Comment: @AndrewL. look, I did everything except line the edges of the picture:
http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0719/h_1468905967_3397040_dc891c697a.png

Comment: @AndrewL. https://jsfiddle.net/u8g7sdt3/  there is no bootstrap I hope you will understand my code

Comment: @TriSTaR Just apply the border-radius:10px to the image

Answer (score 0):

see here : 
http://cssdeck.com/labs/anxnrkhr 
in your case you gonna use png image in `a:hover:before` background